# Get regexp group only if matching

Tags: regex

I have two strings

```
"#string1" (1111) {string2}
"#string1" (1111)
```

I'd like to write regex that would match three groups. For first string:

```
1 => #string1
2 => 1111
3 => string2
```

and for second string

```
1 => #string1
2 => 1111
3 =>
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to produce all three groups but make the third one empty if the string doesn't contain curly braces. I can either match all three groups for first string and none for the second or match first two groups for both strings.

How should me regexp look like?

Comment: Any specific language?

Comment: **Show us what you've tried so far.**  Don't describe it, but edit the question and paste in the actual code.  Then tell us what didn't work.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
^"([^"]*)" \(([^)]*)\)(?: \{([^}]*)\})?$
```